# How to double (or triple) each element of equation?

Tags: graphics, functions, image-processing, algebraic-manipulation, geometric-transform

```
x^2/3+y^2/9==1
(0.5x)^2/3+(0.5*y)^2/9==1
```

Looks at above two equation,I multiply 0.5 to each element of second equation,which means when plotting, each point `x,y` will become `2x,2y`.I use this method to enlarge plotting object .
[image][image]
But as to complex equation like `y^4+2y^2*x-3xy+7x^3==176.984` or `r==Sqrt[Sin[2 θ]]`,I want to ask how to use mathematica built in function to make it easy?

Comment: Take a look at `Scale`

Comment: @Kuba,I want to make data changed,not the scale.

Comment: `Scale` does not change the scale; it scales the data, although it scales the output, not the input, data. The change you are looking for is called scaling, but you seem to want to transform the input, not the output.

Comment: @MichaelE2,I need to put plots in one scale,then I need to find the method to transform input.

Comment: What do you mean by scale?  The axes and/or plot range?  That is not what `Scale` affects (or affects them only indirectly depending on the setting of `PlotRange`).

Comment: Can you *please* include your expected output for scaling `r==Sqrt[Sin[2 θ]]`?

Comment: @jjc385,should be `2*Sqrt[Sin[2 θ]]`,Michael E2's answer has the polar transform function.

Comment: @kittygirl: So for a equation in polar coordinates, you could just replace `r` with `0.5 r`?

Comment: @NikiEstner,NO,just in this case

Comment: @kittygirl Thanks!  It really helps when we explicitly know what you want.  In regard to Niki's comment, should any equation $f(r,\theta)=0$ be transformed to $f(t r, \theta)=0$, where $t$ is the scale factor?

Comment: Have you tried using `PlotRange->{{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax}}`?

Comment: I am getting the sense that you are not immediately realizing that you can use the stuff in the answers to some of your previous problems to solve this particular problem. For instance, you've been told that parametric equations can be easily scaled by multiplying the components by the scale factor. Since polar coordinates easily convert to parametric equations, this also implies that multiplying a polar equation by the scale factor will also do the scaling you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an equation $F(x,y)=0$ and a transformation $t(x,y)$ that, say, scales **points** by $2$, then to scale the graph of $F=0$, one applies the inverse transformation and plots $F(t^{-1}(x,y))=0$.

```
transformEQ[t_, vars_, eq_] :=
  Function[vars, eq] @@ InverseFunction[t]@vars;

equation = y^4 + 2 y^2*x - 3 x y + 7 x^3 == 176.984;
transformEQ[ScalingTransform[{2, 2}], {x, y}, equation]
(*  (7 x^3)/8 - (3 x y)/4 + (x y^2)/4 + y^4/16 == 176.984  *)
```

In polar coordinates, or in another coordinate system, one either converts the coordinates or the transformation $t$.  Since transformations in cartesian coordinates are built into *Mathematica*, the first point of view seems convenient.

```
transformEQ[t_, vars_, eq_, "Polar"] :=
  Function[vars, eq] @@ Simplify[       (* simplifying is optional *)
    Composition[
      ToPolarCoordinates,
      InverseFunction@t,
      FromPolarCoordinates
      ][vars],
    {First@vars > 0, -Pi < Last@vars < Pi}]; (* match the branch cuts of ArcTan[x, y] *)

polar = r == Sqrt[Sin[2 θ]];
transformEQ[ScalingTransform[{2, 2}], {r, θ}, polar, "Polar"]
(*  r/2 == Sqrt[Sin[2 θ]]  *)
```

Note: The assumption on the angle generally produces the correct formula, sometimes even when the condition is not met.  If a transformed equation seems incorrect, then I would check this first.

This could be extended to other coordinate systems with [`CoordinateTransformData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateTransformData.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) to replace each instance of `x` with `.5 x` and so on:

```
equation = y^4 + 2 y^2*x - 3 x y + 7 x^3 < 176.984;
scaled = equation /. {x -> 0.5 x, y -> 0.5 y}
```

> 0.875 x^3 - 0.75 x y + 0.25 x y^2 + 0.0625 y^4 == 176.984

```
RegionPlot[{equation, scaled}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"equation", "scaled"}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you have many variables and you don't want to write a rule for each one, you can use `Alternatives` (`|`) to match a set of symbols in one rule:

```
equation /. var : (x | y | z | r) :> 0.5 var
```

Comment: Probably the OP's `xy` was meant to be separate factors `x y`.

Comment: This method can be used in Cartesian coordinate system,but not Angular coordinates like`r==Sqrt[Sin[2\[Theta]]`

Comment: @kittygirl I highly suggest you edit the question to explicitly state that you're interested in such cases.  I entirely ignored that subtlety.  (Actually, it would be very useful if you'd give your expected output from scaling the equation `r==Sqrt[Sin[2 θ]]`.)

Comment: @Niki Estner,I cannot understand one problem,`ContourPlot[scaled, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 1]` has nothing to display but `RegionPlot` display well.

Comment: @kittygirl there's not much sense in scaling angular coodrdinate.

Comment: @VsevolodA. I think this is precisely kittygirl's point (at least elsewhere, like comments under my answer).  It's the radial coordinate that should be scaled in the polar case.

Comment: @kittygirl Regarding the `ContourPlot` issue, `scaled` is an inequality, whereas `ContourPlot` is expecting an expression to evaluate.  You can instead do `ContourPlot[Evaluate@First@scaled, ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your variables: `./{x->0.5x,y->0.5y}`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I entirely ignored the subtlety of what should happen in polar coordinates.  See OP's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167431/how-to-double-or-triple-each-element-of-equation/167438#comment442047_167435).

---

A version of what others have suggested that find the variables for you.

<sub>(There's a lot of machinery in this answer -- tbh, writing it was largely an exercise in using such machinery for me.  As such, please do ask me about anything that's too much to absorb with a quick look at the docs.)</sub>

### Definition

```
ClearAll[scaleLHS]
Options[scaleLHS] = {"variables" -> Automatic};

scaleLHS[a_ == b_, scaleFactor_, OptionsPattern[] ] :=
    Module[{vars = OptionValue@"variables"},
        vars = Switch[vars
            , Automatic, Variables@a
            , _Symbol, {vars}
            , _Function, vars[a]
            , _, vars
        ];
        (a /. Thread[vars -> scaleFactor*vars]) == b
    ]

(* thread over lists of equations *)
scaleLHS[eqList_List, args__] := scaleLHS[#, args] & /@ eqList

(* operator form, because these can be incredibly useful *)
scaleLHS[scaleFactor : (_Symbol | _?NumericQ), args___?(MatchQ[_Rule | {___Rule}])][eq_] := 
    scaleLHS[eq, scaleFactor, args]
```

### Usage

The variables can often be discovered for you automatically.  This works whenever [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) returns the right variables:

```
scaleLHS[c] @ {x^2/3 + y^2/9 == 1, y^4 + 2 y^2*x - 3 x y + 7 x^3 == 176.984}
```

> ```
> {(c^2 x^2)/3 + (c^2 y^2)/9 == 1, 7 c^3 x^3 - 3 c^2 x y + 2 c^3 x y^2 + c^4 y^4 == 176.984}
> ```

`Variables` treats the entire trig function as a variable, so you need to manually specify `θ` :

```
scaleLHS[Sqrt[Sin[2 θ]] == r, c, "vars" -> θ]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[Sin[2 c θ]] == r
> ```

### Possible improvements

- Define an analagous function `scaleRHS`

  - Until then, just do `Reverse@scaleLHS[Reverse@equation, scaleFactor]`
- Allow different variables to be scaled differently
- Deal with e.g. polar coordinates in the way [OP would like](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167431/how-to-double-or-triple-each-element-of-equation/167438#comment442047_167435)

  - Probably looks like adding an additional option (e.g., "coordinates" -> "Polar"), and some extra work